# PgPool2 alternative for load balancing in Postgresql cluster

Tags: load-balancing, postgresql

I'm using PgBouncer for connection pooling, native psql replication in master-slave mode and PgPool2 for load balancing.

After a few (many) attempts to get PgPool2 playing nice I give up.
To many instability, requests that got "stuck", connections lost, I tried all configurations that I could manage to think of and read the documentations times without count, nothing got me rid of the instability introduced on the environment by PgPool2.

I'm looking for alternatives, I already tried HAProxy but got walled trying to get write queries to master only.

Does anyone know another alternative for load balancing psql in master-slave mode?